# steps or guide to create digital pixelation effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, photoshop-effects, effects, digital

I want to know how this effect can be created in  Photoshop or illustrator

[image: digital pixelation effect]

Comment: Hi corefragments, we are a help resource for the graphic design professional and enthousiast, not a tutorial-on-demand site. Please look for tutorials online and try to follow them. If you get stuck doing a specific step, we'll be glad to help.

Comment: @PieBie Thanks for pointing this out but I posted this question after searching the web for tutorial and coming up empty handed . I,m not looking for tutorials but help in actually replicating this effect which I,m not sure what it's called . I should have title my question a it better.

Answer (score 2):

It's a custom Photoshop brush you can download for free at [www.123freebrushes.com/square-sparkle/](https://www.123freebrushes.com/square-sparkle/)

Once loaded:

- Remove the rotation going to **Brush Presets** > **Shape Dynamics** > move the **Angle Jitter** slider to 0
- To increase the separation, go to **Brush Tip Shape** and drag the **Spacing** slider
- From **Brush Presets** > **Scattering** > modify the **Scatter** options

[image: brush]

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with effect with the *Brush Tool* in Photoshop.

Comment: Can you please elaborate further? Possibly include screenshots as well. As it stands this is more of a comment then an answer.

Comment: Thank you WELZ for your request. I think Danielillo did this already very good with screenshots, i work with Photoshop and i can confirm this. Please understand my posting as an confirmation related to Danielillo.